# Advanced Model Binding vs 2010

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Can I have an example of advanced model binding using ajaxpost?

I have two classes Person and Test as follows:

```
 public class person{
    public ArrayList Name = new ArrayList();
    public Test []test {get;set;}
    }

public class Test
    {
    public int ID{get;set;}
    public int mark{get;set;}
    }
```

My Controller could be

```
[HttpPost]
        public EmptyResult CaseTest(Person person)
        {
            return new EmptyResult();
        }
```

How do I post the values from the view?

Answer (score 2):

To fill the test collection property of your model you could have the following inputs:

```
<input type="text" name="test[0].ID" value="1" />
<input type="text" name="test[0].mark" value="123" />

<input type="text" name="test[1].ID" value="2" />
<input type="text" name="test[1].mark" value="456" />
```

As far as the `ArrayList` field is concerned you should use a generic strongly typed collection and use a property with getter and setter instead of field for better encapsulation.

I would also encourage you reading [this blog post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx) from [Scott Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/) in which he covers advanced binding scenarios.

Comment: Thanks Dariv.  I have to use javascript to do as above and I have posted the remaining of the question on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3036751/test-is-null-in-the-controller-upon-post.